# How to find out if a given resource of a JID is online/offline with smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

How can I tell that a juliet@verona.it/balkony (full JID!) is online/still available with smack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to `juliet@verona.it`'s presence, go online by sending your own presence in, and see if you get a presence stanza back.  Querying for presence doesn't actually make much sense; think of it as stepping into the flow of juliet's presence at a certain point in time.